# The item position in the RecyclerView is not saved

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

I use the mode adjustResize, RecyclerView and EditText, when the keyboard appears, the window shrinks but the visible elements in the RecyclerView go down.

[image]
[image]

The structure of the layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I set setStackFromEnd to true, in LinearManager but it does not help.

Versions of libraries: 25.3.0

How can this unpleasant problem be avoided?

Comment: The parent layout should be RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.

Comment: I replaced LinearLayout on RelativeLayout but it did not help.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
add about attribute in manifest or if its already added than remove it and than check whether its work.

make sure parent layout is RelativeLayout as mentioned in 1st comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using linear layout on top use Relative layout like following...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_view"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```